# Can't figure out horizontal scrolling for page

Tags: jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I'm working on a hierarchy page and am having trouble getting it to scroll, it should scroll horizontally off of the screen to show all the departments but instead it's just creating the new department below the others and looks kind of weird (as seen with Test Department 7 in my screenshot), it should be creating test department 7 off of the screen and allowing for scrolling. I have included the css being used to create the hierarchy as well as a screenshot to explain what I mean. The whole hierarchy is based off of http://astuteo.com/slickmap/ what's here. I'm fresh out of ideas and any new thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks. Would there maybe be some jquery I could use for this that would target #primaryNav or something?[image]

----In .ascx file -----

I'm using knockoutjs here to create the hierarchy

```
<div class="row-fluid" data-bind="if: MapViewVisible, visible: Items().length > 0" style="display: none;">
    <div class="span12" data-bind="visible: MapViewVisible">
        <ul id="primaryNav" class="col10" data-bind="template: { name: 'root-template', foreach: Hierarchy}">

        </ul>            
    </div>
</div>
```

----CSS------

```
#primaryNav li {
width:25%;
}

#primaryNav li ul li {
width:100% !important;
}

#primaryNav.col1 li { width:99.9%; }
#primaryNav.col2 li { width:50.0%; }
#primaryNav.col3 li { width:33.3%; }
#primaryNav.col4 li { width:25.0%; }
#primaryNav.col5 li { width:20.0%; }
#primaryNav.col6 li { width:16.6%; }
#primaryNav.col7 li { width:14.2%; }
#primaryNav.col8 li { width:12.5%; }
#primaryNav.col9 li { width:11.1%; }
#primaryNav.col10 li { width:12.5%; }

/* ------------------------------------------------------------
    General Styles
------------------------------------------------------------ */

body {
/*background: white;
color: black;
padding: 40px;
font-family: Gotham, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1;*/
}
.sitemap {
margin: 0 0 40px 0;
float: left;
width: 100%;
}
h1 {
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 20px;
margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
h2 {
font-family: "Arial", Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 10px;
color: #777777;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}


/* ------------------------------------------------------------
Site Map Styles
------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* -------- Top Level --------- */

#primaryNav {
margin: 0;
float: left;
width: 200%; /*tried this and overflow but didnt seem to work*/
overflow-x:auto;
}
#primaryNav #home {
display: block;
float: none;
background: #ffffff url('/_layouts/images/barium/lines/L1-left.png') center bottom     no-repeat;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
padding: 10px 0 30px 0;
}
#primaryNav li {
float: left;
background: url('/_layouts/images/barium/lines/L1-center.png') center top no-repeat;
padding: 30px 0;
margin-top: -30px;
}
#primaryNav li a {
margin: 0 20px 0 0;
padding: 10px 0;
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
color: black;   
background: #c3eafb url('/_layouts/images/barium/lines/white-highlight.png') top left repeat-x;
border: 2px solid #b5d9ea;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 2px 2px 2px; 
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 2px 2px 2px; /* FF 3.5+ */
}

#primaryNav li a:hover {
background-color: #e2f4fd;
border-color: #97bdcf;
}
#primaryNav li:last-child {
background: url('/_layouts/images/barium/lines/L1-right.png') center top no-repeat;
}

#primaryNav a:link:before,
#primaryNav a:visited:before {
/*content: " "attr(href)" ";*/
display: block;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 10px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
#primaryNav li a:link:before,
#primaryNav li a:visited:before {
color: #78a9c0;
}

/* -------- Second Level --------- */

#primaryNav li li {
width: 100%;
clear: left;
margin-top: 0;
padding: 10px 0 0 0;
background: url('/_layouts/images/barium/lines/vertical-line.png') center bottom repeat-y;
}
#primaryNav li li a {
background-color: #cee3ac;
border-color: #b8da83;
}
#primaryNav li li a:hover {
border-color: #94b75f;
background-color: #e7f1d7;
}
#primaryNav li li:first-child {
padding-top: 30px;
}
#primaryNav li li:last-child {
background: url('/_layouts/images/barium/lines/vertical-line.png') center bottom repeat-y;
}
#primaryNav li li a:link:before,
#primaryNav li li a:visited:before {
color: #8faf5c;
}

/* -------- Third Level --------- */

#primaryNav li li ul {
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
width: 100%;
float: right;
padding: 9px 0 10px 0;
background: #ffffff url('/_layouts/images/barium/lines/L3-ul-top.png') center top no-repeat;
}
#primaryNav li li li {
background: url('/_layouts/images/barium/lines/L3-center.png') left center no-repeat;
padding: 5px 0;
}
#primaryNav li li li a {
background-color: #fff7aa;
border-color: #e3ca4b;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 5px 0;
width: 80%;
float: right;
}
#primaryNav li li li a:hover {
background-color: #fffce5;
border-color: #d1b62c;
}
#primaryNav li li li:first-child {
padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
background: url('/_layouts/images/barium/lines/L3-li-top.png') left center no-repeat;
}
#primaryNav li li li:last-child {
background: url('/_layouts/images/barium/lines/L3-bottom.png') left center no-repeat;
}
#primaryNav li li li a:link:before,
#primaryNav li li li a:visited:before {
color: #ccae14;
font-size: 9px;
}

li a p, li a .nofontweight
{
font-weight:400;
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping the whole thing in a DIV, setting a width to it and `overflow: auto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class (row-fluid) outside the primary UL container has a width constraint. If you set .row_fluid with a `overflow:auto`, that should do the trick.

However, without seeing an much of a working sample, that is all I can evaluate for now.

jsFiddle.net is a great place to post and test sample code.

Comment: hmmmm tried but it didnt do anything, I'm thinking it has something to do with the col10: width and the width of primaryNav in some sort of combination, I'm just not sure how to write the jquery to mess around with this if possible.

Comment: Can you jsFiddle this with some sample data?  We really don't have enough information to work with what is posted.

Comment: The data is all in sharepoint lists, it basically loops through in the backend and gets the number of departments, department names etc, and creates a new tile for each department it finds. So giving sample data may be a little difficult, sorry.

Comment: Would it help if I gave the entirety of the code for the ascx page where everything is? (including the above code)

Comment: No, you don't need to go that far. On the rendered page, go to view source and copy that HTML only.  Paste the HTML along with your CSS into jsFiddle.net and provide the link here.

Comment: I was able to get the link and it looks somewhat the way it looks now, here you go http://jsfiddle.net/JWKCX/